# Add Amadeus airport and city search autocomplete to Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, autocomplete, amadeus

**What is the best way to send a request to the Amadeus API with a form field that uses autocomplete in a Rails app?**

I am adding autocomplete to a search form to query the **Amadeus "Airport and City Search"**.

I am using Rails 6 and `gem 'amadeus'`.

I get a 401 Unauthorized error when I type 3 letters into the search form. How can I authorize my request and make this autocomplete work?

Here is my javascript:

```
$(function() {
    function log(message) {
      $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
      $("#log").scrollTop(0);
    }
    $("#city").autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            apikey: "my_api_key_here",
            keyword: request.term
          },
          success: function(data) {
            response(data);
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 3,
      select: function(event, ui) {
        log(ui.item ?
          "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
      },
      open: function() {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
      },
      close: function() {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Rails but I believe you could redirect the AJAX request to the backend and make the API call using the Ruby library you have installed. These links could be useful even though they use different stacks but the logic should be similar: 
- https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/airport-autocomplete-jquery-ajax
- https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/django-jquery-ajax-airport-search-autocomplete

Comment: Also as a best practice it's good to store your credentials on backend and not client side, otherwise they'll be accessible from others.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an authorized request with javascript using the gon gem to get the access token in javascript.

```
$(function() {
  amadeus_client = gon.amadeus
  function log(message) {
    $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
    $("#log").scrollTop(0);
  }
  console.log("Requesting Token...");
  var settings = {
    "url": "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token",
    "method": "POST",
    "timeout": 0,
    "data": {
      "client_id": amadeus_client.client_id,
      "client_secret": amadeus_client.client_secret,
      "grant_type": "client_credentials"
    }
  };
  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log("Assigning Token variables...");
    ACCESS_TOKEN = response.access_token;
    console.log("Access Token : " + ACCESS_TOKEN);
  });
  $("#city").autocomplete({ 
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',
          'Bearer ' + ACCESS_TOKEN);
        },
        data: {
          keyword: request.term,
          subType: "CITY"
        },
        success: function(data){
          // console.log(data);
          response($.map(data.data, function(el){
            return {
              label: el.detailedName,
              value: el.iataCode
            }
          }));
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      log(ui.item ?
        "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
        "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
    },
    open: function() {
      $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
    },
    close: function() {
      $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
    }
  });
});
```